# How to calculate the number of a specific weekday between two POSIXct date arrays and return another numerical array?

Tags: r, date, apply, posixct, weekday

I wrote a formula based on a weekday calculating algorithm (found in Stackexchange as well, great job guys. Here is the code snippet:

```
countwd <- function(start, end, day){
  x <- seq(start, end, by=1)
  y <- weekdays(x, TRUE)
  sum(y==day)
}
x$OFFDAY <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  x$OFFDAY[i] <- countwd(x$PICK_DATE[i], x$SHIP_DATE[i], "Mon")
}
```

This is way too slow (loop proceeds like 2-4 rows per second!!!!), and I have millions of entries for each month.

Here is the vectorisation of the function:

```
x$OFFDAY <- countwd(x$PICK_DATE, x$SHIP_DATE, "Mon")
```

Shows this error:

> Error in seq.POSIXt(start, end, by = 1) : 'from' must be of length 1

I cannot understand how to apply the "apply" family functions in this case as I have two vectors to compare (yes, I am really new to this).

Sample Data:

```
PICK_DATE   SHIP_DATE
01-APR-2017 00:51   02-APR-2017 06:55 AM
01-APR-2017 00:51   02-APR-2017 12:11 PM
01-APR-2017 00:51   02-APR-2017 12:11 PM
01-APR-2017 00:51   02-APR-2017 09:39 AM
```

I have converted these to POSIXct, and the formula works well for individual values (returns the second value though, no idea why. However, I can work around that):

```
>countwd(x$PICK_DATE[1], x$SHIP_DATE[1], "Mon")
[1] 0
```

Comment: You need to use `mapply` when you want to apply a function to more than one list or vector argument. Here you would do `x$OFFDAY <- mapply(FUN = countwd, start = x$PICK_DATE, end = x$SHIP_DATE, day = "Mon")`. But it may still be slow, if the dates are far apart. There is probably a faster way using the `lubridate` package but I'll need to think on it.

Comment: Are you sure this works as intended when `countwd` is given individual values? Have you tried a case where it should return 1 or 2 (and not 0)?

Comment: Yes, `countwd` gives the right count, but not in days. I have no idea why, but it gives seconds.

Comment: @meenaparam, if you can provide any alternative solution, that will also be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @demirev's answer and my comments above, here is a worked example using the improved `countwd` function and `mapply`. I put in a few helper columns using `lubridate` to check the solution, and changed some of the dates to return values to `df$off_days` that were not zero.

```
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(pick_date = c(rep("01-APR-2017 00:51", 4)), ship_date = c("05-APR-2017 06:55", "09-APR-2017 12:11", "30-APR-2017 12:11", "02-MAY-2017 12:11"))

df$pick_date <- lubridate::dmy_hm(df$pick_date)
df$ship_date <- lubridate::dmy_hm(df$ship_date)

df$pick_day <- wday(df$pick_date, label = T)
df$ship_day <- wday(df$ship_date, label = T)
df$days_between <- interval(df$pick_date, df$ship_date) %/% days()

countwd <- function(start, end, day) {
    x <- seq(start, end, by="day")
    y <- weekdays(x, TRUE)
    sum(y==day)
}

df$off_days <- mapply(countwd, df$pick_date, df$ship_date, "Mon")
df

            pick_date           ship_date pick_day ship_day days_between off_days
1 2017-04-01 00:51:00 2017-04-05 06:55:00      Sat      Wed            4        1
2 2017-04-01 00:51:00 2017-04-09 12:11:00      Sat      Sun            8        1
3 2017-04-01 00:51:00 2017-04-30 12:11:00      Sat      Sun           29        4
4 2017-04-01 00:51:00 2017-05-02 12:11:00      Sat     Tues           31        5
```

Comment: Yup, formatting problem. Probably it comes from how I parse the PICK_DATE column. I used the formula before parsing and it went smooth. I have to parse the dates as to change their hour value according to their hour value. Like if you order after 5PM, your order will be processed from next morning 9AM, and lead time will be calculated as per that.

Comment: @Arani I see, well, check out `lubridate` - there are simple ways to add times together using this package. See the section on "Arithmetic with date times". https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to vectorize a function of multiple varying inputs is to use `mapply`:

```
mapply(countwd, x$SHIP_DATE, x$PICK_DATE, "Mon")
```

Or, alternatively, you can use `sapply` and pass a sequence of indices as a first argument (this way the syntax is very similar to a `for` loop:

`sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) countwd(x$SHIP_DATE[i], x$PICK_DATE[i], "Mon"))`

The main inefficiency in your case however stems from the `countwd` function. Notice that you are passing `POSIXt` vectors to the function. Thus, when `seq` is called in the first row of the function, the `by` argument is taken to be seconds instead of days! This leads to generating needlessly large vectors (see `?seq.POSIXt` for details).

Changing `countwd` in the following way should greatly improve performance:

```
countwd <- function(start, end, day) {
    x <- seq(start, end, by="day")
    y <- weekdays(x, TRUE)
    sum(y==day)
}
```

Also note that `weekdays` is locale-specific and may not work as intended depending on your locale settings.

Comment: Awesome suggestion. However, using `mapply` gives this error: _zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length_. Using `sapply` gives this error: _'from' must be of length 1_. If you could suggest how you would approach the problem from scratch, it would have been better for me.

Comment: @Arani Sorry, I can't come up with anything better. The changes proposed by @demirev to the `countwd` function do seem to fix things. I've put in a full worked example as I guess your `mapply` isn't working because your data isn't correctly formatted.

Comment: Yeah, just found out that somethng weird is going on. The data was replaced!! I got the backup and now `mapply` & `sapply` both give this error: _Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument_.